# checking the quality of filtering of a temporal series

Tags: curve-fitting, filter

I have many temporal series of satellite data. I decided to smooth that using Savitzky-Golay filter implemented in R using the "signal" package. 
I could use also other smoothing algorithms, that's not the core of the question.
Is there a benchmark that testify the best "compromise" between the level of smoothing and the original data.